# Short story about gigantism potion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novella

Someone accidentally devised a chemical/potion which caused anything it touched to grow massively - IIRC the first example was dandelions ten feet tall. The initial protagonists (a couple familes) tried this on infants, and they got enormous, and IIRC also more intelligent.

There was a lot of discussion of the political ramifications, many people being concerned what this would do to society and trying to keep it from spreading. The end of the story featured the giants, now adult (and therefore even bigger) declaring that they couldn't be prevented, and intended to apply it to their own children to make them *even bigger*. The last line was something like

> "We will not be deterred from progress! Ever larger and ever greater, until the globe is but a stepstool!"

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this story, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, did you read it in a magazine, an anthology, or online?

Comment: Don't remember and don't remember. Probably before 2010, not online.

Comment: That sounds a lot like the famous novel by H.G. Wells, *The Food of the Gods and How It Came to Earth*.

Comment: I think you've got it @Adamant , one of the final lines is "Till the earth is no more than a footstool.... "

Comment: @Adamant - Needs posting as an answer

Answer (score 8):

Like Adamant, I was immediately reminded of the novel (rather than a short story), divided into three parts, by H.G. Wells entitled "[The Food of the Gods and How It Came to Earth](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?906139)", published in 1904.

It deals with an invention by two bumbling scientists, Bensington and Redwood, who devise a food that cause living organisms to grow to enormous size. They, with their classical education call it "Herakleophorbia 4" ("the food of Heracles"), the public call it "boomfood", and it is "the food of the gods" of the title.

It was first tested on chickens, and also spread to plants - notably nettles and thistles, but I don't remember dandelions being involved - and other accidents produced pests like giant spiders, rats, and so on.

They went on to treat humans with it who grew to enormous size. There was no augmentation of intelligence that you mention in the question though. Tensions grow between the humans and the giants and lead to an ultimatum: the humans demand that the giants move to an empty area where they will be provided with boomfood (essential for their life), on the condition that they do not reproduce. The line you recall comes form the giant delivering a speech to his followers rejecting this plan:

> Tomorrow, whether we live or we die, growth will conquer through us.
> That is the law of the spirit for evermore... To grow at last into the
> fellowship and understanding of God. Growing... Till the earth is no
> more than a footstool... Till the spirit shall have driven fear into
> nothingness, and spread..." He swung his arms heavenward - "There!"

"Till the earth is no more than a footstool" fits almost perfectly the line you remember.

The full text is available from [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/11696/11696-h/11696-h.htm#link2HCH0004).